# Computing $E[X^2]$ for geometric random variable

Tags: probability, expected-value

I am trying to compute the $E[X^2]$ where $X$ is a geometric random variable. I computed $E[X]$ using the logic that $X$ can either be 1 (meaning we get a success on the first try) with probability $p$, or we fail the first try, in which case, we have wasted a try and will have to start over, so we have

\begin{align}
    E[X] = 1*p + (1-p)*(1+E[X])  \\
    E[X] - (1-p)*(1+E[X]) = p \\ 
    -1 + p +pE[X] = p \\
    \therefore E[X] = \frac{1}{p}
\end{align}

And then I tried to do the following 
$$
E[X^2] = 1^2 * p + (1-p)*(1+E[X])^2 = p + (1-p)(1+2E[X]+E[X]^2)
$$
But this step seems to be wrong, and it seems the correct way would be
$$
E[X^2] = 1^2*p + (1-p)(1+2E[X]+E[X^2])   \neq p + (1-p)(1+2E[X]+E[X]^2)
$$

Why is my former approach not correct? I thought I correctly applied the law of the unconscious statistician:
$$
E[g(x)] = \sum_{x} g(x) f(x) \\
$$
In this case $g(x) = x^2$, so couldn't I simply square the $(1+E[X])$ term?

Comment: You seem to be asking why $$\sum_x x^2 f(x) \neq \left(\sum_x x f(x)\right)^2.$$  Is that right?

Comment: @BrianMoehring No. What gave you that impression?

Comment: @BrianMoehring In my case, I thought $x$ took on the values of $1$ and $1+E[X]$.

Comment: It is effectively what you are doing.  I was more asking whether you could see the connection rather than asking whether that is explicitly your question.  As for your second comment, I don't know what you mean.  See my answer below for a more in-depth answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the details for evaluating $E[X]$:

$$\begin{align*}\sum_{x=1}^\infty x f(x) &= 1\cdot p + (1-p)\sum_{x=1}^\infty (x+1) f(x) \\ &= 1\cdot p + (1-p)\left(\sum_{x=1}^\infty f(x) + \sum_{x=1}^\infty xf(x)\right) \\ &= 1 \cdot p + (1-p)\left(1 + \sum_{x=1}^\infty x f(x)\right)\end{align*}$$

Here are the details for evaluating $E[X^2]$:
$$\begin{align*}\sum_{x=1}^\infty x^2 f(x) &= 1^2\cdot p + (1-p)\sum_{x=1}^\infty (x+1)^2 f(x) \\ &= 1^2\cdot p + (1-p)\left(\sum_{x=1}^\infty f(x) + 2\sum_{x=1}^\infty xf(x) + \sum_{x=1}^\infty x^2f(x)\right) \\ &= 1^2 \cdot p + (1-p)\left(1 + 2\sum_{x=1}^\infty x f(x) + \sum_{x=1}^\infty x^2f(x)\right)\end{align*}$$

Note that you can never bring the square on $x^2$ out of the sum.

---

Here, in both cases we've used $f(x+1) = (1-p)f(x)$ for the geometric distribution.  Other than that, it's just reparametrization and algebra.

Comment: Haven't fully finished reading your post yet, but I wanted to ask something. In my OP, is it correct for me to say that $X$ can take on the value 1 or the value $1+E[X]$?

Comment: I simply thought that the following is true:
$$
\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} xf(x) = \sum_{x=\{1, 1+E[X]\}} x f(x) \\
$$
but this seems to be wrong based on your answer.

Comment: No.  The possible values of $X$ is $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$.  This doesn't change.  To go further on this topic, I would need to invoke conditional expectation.  Are you comfortable with conditional expectation?

Comment: Yes, I am. Thanks.

Comment: I think what made me think that $x$ can take on the values 1 or $1+E[X]$ was because of the expression in my OP where I wrote $E[X] = 1*p + (1+E[X])(1-p)$. We know that there are 2 events: X=1 (success on the first trial) or X=1+E[X]  (fail the first trial and start over)

Comment: All right.  Then what you're dealing with is 
$$E[X] = 1\cdot P(X=1) + E[X \mid X > 1] P(X > 1) = 1\cdot P(X=1) + E[X+1] P(X > 1)$$
and 
$$E[X^2] = 1^2 P(X=1) + E[X^2 \mid X > 1] P(X > 1) = 1^2 P(X=1) + E[(X+1)^2] P(X>1)$$
In the former, we have $E[X]+1$, but in the latter, $E[(X+1)^2] \neq E[X+1]^2$

Comment: Ah I think I understand now. Just so I get my terminology right: the conditional expectation of $X$ given that we fail the 1st trial, $E[X|X>1]$, is not called an event? When I think of expectation in words, I think of the sum of the product of events and their respective probability, which makes me inclined to say that  $E[X|X>1]$ is an event, but that doesn't seem wrong terminologically. What you applied here is the law of total expectation, which I think in words, says "the sum of the product of the expectation of $X$ conditioned on an event in $X$ and the respective event probability."

Comment: An event needs to be a subset of the sample space, so "We fail the first trial" (equivalently "$X > 1$") is an event.  The conditional expectation of a random variable given an event is a number, not an event.  I agree that I've applied the law of total expectation here, though -- in particular, the law of total expectation with respect to a set of events that partition the sample space ($X=1$ and $X>1$)

Comment: Sorry, one more question. How does your comment showing the conditional expectation derivation relate to your derivations in your answer? Were you demonstrating 2 different ways to solve the problem?

Comment: Apologies for jumping in. Why is $E[X|X>1] = E[X+1]$?

Comment: Functionally they are the same.  However, when you started saying "Is it correct for me to say that $X$ can take on the value $1$ or the value $1+E[X]$?" this type of averaging of averages is best explained by the law of total expectation.

Comment: Ohhh so I've solved a lot of problems using something like $E[X] = 1*p + (1+E[X])*(1-p)$. I think all of this time, I thought I was applying the definition of expectation, which I kind of am (because the yield the same answer), but after your comments on conditional expectation, I think I was really applying the law of total expectation.

Comment: @user5965026 This is one of the properties of geometric random variables.

Comment: @user5965026 I'll take a crack at answering your question. $X$ can take on values $\in \{1,2,3,\cdots, \infty\}$. If we are given that $X > 1$, then this means that $X|X>1$ can only be $\in \{2,3,4\cdots, \infty\}$, which is the set of values that $X+1$ can take on.

Comment: Does that mean $X|X>1 = X+1$ or only E[X|X>1] = E[X+1]?

Comment: @user5965026 In distribution, yes. We have $X \mid X > 1$ and $X+1$ have the same distribution.  (I'm not sure if $X \mid X > 1 = X+1$ makes any sense as equality of random variables)

Comment: In your answer, where you wrote 
$$
E[X] = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}xf(x) = 1p + (1-p)\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} (x+1)f(x)
$$
I'm trying to figure out how you got this equivalence.


$$
E[X] = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}xf(x) = 1*p + \sum_{x=2}^{\infty} xf(x) = 1*p + \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} (x+1)f(x+1) \\
f(x+1) = f(x|x>1)f(x>1) = f(x|x>1)(1-p)
$$
I'm not sure what to do with $f(x|x>1)$. Is this simply equal to $f(x)$? That seems to be the only possibility but it's not intuitive to me. Could you please explain?

Comment: I did see that you mentioned $f(x+1) = (1-p)f(x)$ due to the definition of a geometric variable, but I'm trying to think about this in terms of conditional probability.